# Formatting individual variables in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a simple question. I have a large dataset with text and numerical variables. I would like to format the numerical variables, but without saving them in a separate dataset and re-merging them (that would take way to much time).

How do I do this?

Here is a minimal example of what I mean:

```
a <- c("name1", "name2", "name3")
b <- rnorm(3)

df <- data.frame(a=a, b=b)

df<- format(round(df, 3), nsmall=3)
```

This gives me an error as "a" is a non-numeric variable. So how do I format just "b"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format one column:

```
df$b <- format(round(df$b, 3), nsmall = 3)
```

If we need to format many numeric columns:

```
ix <- sapply(df, is.numeric)
df[ ix ] <- format(round(df[ ix ], 3), nsmall = 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

And a `tidyverse`-based solution for arbitrary number (and location) of numeric columns:

```
library(tidyverse)

df<- df %>%
    mutate_if(is.numeric, . %>% round(3) %>% format(nsmall=3))

df
      a      b
1 name1 -0,105
2 name2  0,186
3 name3  0,161
```